# Customizing react-leaflet marker icons by using font awesome

Tags: leaflet, font-awesome, react-leaflet

It is more theoretical question, rather than a problem.

How to use **font awesome icons** as ***react-leaflet map marker icons***?

I would like to have such an icon selector control to assign(customize) each marker icon I have got on my map. By the way I am using JSX components of Map and Marker.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Anybody have a sample pen about this? I have really googled it strongly but couldn't find any plugin but a fontawesome plugin that is working only with Leaflet 1.0.

So any idea appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**For some reasons code is not getting formatted. See code on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4ry180jl34)**

Here is how you can use font-awesome icons as markers.

1. Add font-awesome CDN to your `index.html`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
 crossorigin="anonymous">`

2. Use `divIcon` along with `renderToStaticMarkup` from `react-dom/server` to generate icon for marker.  And pass this `divIcon` to `Marker` as a `icon` prop.

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
   import { divIcon } from 'leaflet';
   import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

   import './styles.css';

   class App extends Component {
     state = {
       lat: 51.505,
       lng: -0.091,
       zoom: 13,
     };

   render() {
       const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
       const iconMarkup = renderToStaticMarkup(<i className=" fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-3x" />);
       const customMarkerIcon = divIcon({
         html: iconMarkup,
       });

       return (
         <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
           <TileLayer
             attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
             url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
           />
           <Marker position={position} icon={customMarkerIcon}>
             <Popup>
               A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
             </Popup>
           </Marker>
         </Map>
       );
     }
   }

   const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
   ```
3. Override divIcon default style by adding the following class to your css file

   ```
   .leaflet-div-icon {
       background: transparent;
       border: none;
   }
   ```

   - Here is a working example of the same:
     https://codesandbox.io/s/4ry180jl34

Comment: Thank you Murli . You saved me hours! Excellent answer :)

Comment: One more little question: Why is the Map disappearing when it is surrounding by div tags?  Do you have any idea or workaround?

Comment: @H.SerhanEkinci you need to provide height and width to the div.

Comment: any other solution or advice?

Comment: @H.SerhanEkinci you must add `.leaflet-container` class to your css with height and width. Refer code sandbox `style.css` file.

Comment: Worked like a charm:) I appreciate it.

Comment: thank you man, you saved me hours of time

Answer (score 6):

For those who already use the React components of Fontawesome (FontAwesomeIcon), there is a solution that does not require importing via CDN again. It uses the same principles of Murli's answers, but instead of adding `<i className=" fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-3x" />`, you can convert the FontAwesomeIcon component to html and pass that into the html attribute of the divIcon. It would look like this (adapted the example of the accepted answer):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Leaflet from 'leaflet'
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import './styles.css';

// FontAwesome requirements
import { faUserAstronaut } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faUserAstronaut)

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    lat: 51.505,
    lng: -0.091,
    zoom: 13,
  };

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    const iconHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<FontAwesomeIcon icon='user-astronaut' />)
    const customMarkerIcon = new Leaflet.DivIcon({
      html: iconHTML,
    });

    return (
      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position} icon={customMarkerIcon}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This is working for me, thanks! Note that by default, you will get a white square with black border behind the icon, which may not be what you want. [Here is how to remove it.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/291981/51227)

Answer (score -1):

Create `divIcon` and insert it into `icon` property:

```js
// marker-icons.js
import L from 'leaflet';

const factory = new L.divIcon({
  className: '',
  iconAnchor: [12, 25],
  labelAnchor: [-6, 0],
  popupAnchor: [0, -15],
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  html: `<span class="fa fa-industry"></span>`
});

export default { factory };
```

Use icon in component file:

```js
// component.js
import { factory } from './marker-icons';

<MapContainer center={[12.23432, 87.234]} zoom={6} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
    <Marker position={45.4534, 23.43]} icon={factory}>
        <Popup>Help text</Popup>
    </Marker>
</MapContainer>
```